# Nested Joins in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, join

I have 3 models `Company, User, Loan` in my Rails application

**company.rb**

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

---

```
Company id: 1, name: "A", created_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:17", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:17"
Company id: 2, name: "B", created_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:19", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:19"
Company id: 3, name: "C", created_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:21", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:21"
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :loans
end
```

---

```
User id: 1, name: "Sachin", company_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:35:53", updated_at: "2018-02-06 08:02:41", user_status: true
User id: 2, name: "Ghanshyam", company_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:36:01", updated_at: "2018-02-06 08:02:41", user_status: false
User id: 3, name: "Anand", company_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:36:06", updated_at: "2018-02-06 08:02:41", user_status: false
User id: 4, name: "Ghanshyam Rahul", company_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:36:15", updated_at: "2018-02-06 08:02:41", user_status: false
User id: 5, name: "Anand", company_id: 3, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:43:56", updated_at: "2018-02-06 08:02:41", user_status: false
User id: 6, name: "Ghanshyam", company_id: 3, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:43:58", updated_at: "2018-02-06 08:02:41", user_status: false
```

**loan.rb**

```
class Loan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

```
Loan id: 1, name: "loan 1", user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:44:46", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:44:46"
Loan id: 5, name: "loan 5", user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:44:54", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:44:54"
Loan id: 6, name: "loan 6", user_id: 6, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:45:33", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:45:33"
Loan id: 7, name: "loan 7", user_id: 6, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:45:34", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:45:34"
Loan id: 8, name: "loan 8", user_id: 6, created_at: "2018-02-06 07:45:36", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:45:36"
```

I want to write down join query(single query) that fetch list of company if there users have any loan like follows :

```
Company id: 1, name: "A", created_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:17", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:17"
Company id: 3, name: "C", created_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:21", updated_at: "2018-02-06 07:34:21"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Company.joins(users: :loans).distinct
```

Will give you all companies that have users with loan

You create `join` query that will join company with their users, and give you companies with users, and then join users with their loans. As it is using inner join, when users do not have company they do not appear and their companies do not appear either

Answer (score 1):

```
Company.joins(users: [:loans]).group('companies.id')
```

To avoid possible company duplications I would group companies table by company id field.